# Quelle orthographe pour l'expression « Prendre perpète » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, orthographe

*Prendre perpét'* est un [apocope](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_perpette) très utilisé de *Prendre perpétuité*, c'est une expression provenant de l'argot des prisons pour exprimer l'idée d'être [emprisonné à perpétuité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emprisonnement_%C3%A0_perp%C3%A9tuit%C3%A9).

Je me demandais simplement comment il devait être orthographié (avec sources si possible), car après quelques recherches je trouve plusieurs orthographes différentes :

> Prendre perpette
>   Prendre perpète
>   Prendre perpét'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey, 1980)

> **Perpète**, n.f. (**perpette**)
>
> - Perpétuité, dans : *à perpète*, à perpétuité.
> - Condamnation à la réclusion criminelle à vie.
>
> Hist. 1836. Les *perpètes* sont, vers la fin du [19<sup>e</sup> siècle], les travaux forcés à perpétuité.

Le TLF ne donne que [*perpète*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/perp%C3%A8te) et ne connaît pas [*perpette*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perpette). 
Mon correcteur orthographique connaît *perpète* et *perpette*.

Ceci dit qu'est-ce qui empêcherait d'écrire « perpét' » (proposé dans la question mais que je n'ai jamais rencontré) « perpèt' » ou « perpet' » (jamais rencontrés non plus) si on veut reproduire une langue parlée familière.

Comment: Peut-être que la prononciation l'empêcherait...

Comment: @jcm69 Si on reproduit du langage parlé qui ferait la différence entre un accent grave et un accent aigu ?Je n'ai jamais vu perpèt' non plus !

Comment: @Laure Du coup, mieux vaut utiliser *perpète*, qui semble être le terme le plus courant/reconnu, je suppose

Comment: Hmm. Pour *perpét'*, vu qu'il ne suggère pas vraiment la prononciation souhaitée en soi (la prononciation du *t* ne semble pas être licencée), il s'agirait donc d'une allusion au mot écrit plutôt que d'une réproduction d'une langue parlée familière. De plus, comme *perpét'* (toujours « en soi ») n'est pas conforme à l'orthographe française, tandis que les accents aigus se transforment souvent en accents graves pour signaler cette même alternance (/e/ dans une syllabe ouverte qui alterne avec /ɛ/ dans une syllabe fermée), je suis fort tenté de préférer *perpète*.

Comment: @Mistalis *Perpète* ou *perpette*, le *Dictionnaire historique en langue française donne aussi les deux*, le *Petit Robert* donne aussi les deux...  mais tout dépend de l'usage que tu veux en faire, rien n'empêche la création littéraire, surtout dans le langage familier, ma seule limite c'est de rester compris. Opinion personnelle, bien sûr.